# Samba share settings to work only in my home LAN

Tags: debian, samba, shared-directory

I'm trying to set up Samba configuration in "/etc/samba/smb.conf" on Debian to make it work **only** when I'm at home (connected to a certain connection).

I don't want to share my folder when I'm not connected to my home router, because I often use my laptop with public/corporation wifi.

Any configuration suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution adding a script at startup (/etc/init.d folder), made in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10s
wifi="'$(/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 | egrep ESSID | cut -d '"' -f 2)'"
if [ $wifi = "'NAME OF MY HOME WIRELESS CONNECTION'" ]
    then
        service smbd start
        service nmbd start
else
    service smbd stop
    service nmbd stop
fi
```

Any advice is welcome.